# Two users editing same table/resource

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a tool written in CakePHP which among other functionalities, given a list of products, allows me to create orders, purchase orders, product catalogs etc for my clients. However I have multiple users creating and editing these orders which brings me to the question.

How can I show a warning or somehow prevent more than one user to work on the same object? Right now everyone has to ask verbally before editing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: Yes forgot to, it's v 0.2.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flag in table when user requests for product and remove flag on save.. but theres a few additional problems:

- what if user close browser,
- what if user accidentally refresh page
- what if battery dies in users laptop?
- what if user accidentally dies? :)
  ...

My proposition is:

- Add 'datetime' column to your table, lets call it "lock_date":
- Add lock_user_id column to your table,
- When user open product - set lock_date to current datetime, and lock_user_id from session
- On client side: send ajax request to other method every minute for update "lock_date" field with current datetime
- When ANY user tries to open the same product:

1) check if lock_date < current datetime minus 1 minute. If true: allow edit

2) If false: check if lock_user_id == session.user_id. If true - allow edit (this condition is useful if user accidentally refresh page, or try to open the same product when accidentally pressed "back" button, or trying to edit product in other browser)

Comment: This is genius...! I had thought something like this but you gave me the solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `user_id` column to yours tables, once a user request to work with an Entity, you set this `user_id` to the entity and save it on database. It could be defined at the controller `initialize()` function, if the action requested match your condition.

And at `beforeSave()` function, you could set the `user_id` to `null`.

Then, before you render the template you check if `user_id` is `null` to render or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag on the object to that get's set to true when that object is requested for editing and false when the edit has been persisted to the object.

With that flag you could then prevent the object from being edited when

```
if(!flag) {
    //code with form to edit the object
    <form action="object.php" method="post">
      .....
    </form>
} else {
   //either disable the form fields or better solution show message to 
   //user that the object is being edited and they should try again later
   $this->flash->set("This record is currently being edited. Please try again later");
}
```

Comment: These two last methods are somethin like I'm using at the time but the incovenients are stated above by Rayann Nayran, with the date_lock I solved this.